# Calculate Active users per day from Start and End date columns

Tags: sql, concurrency, count, amazon-redshift

I have table like below and I want to create a view of **unique active users per day**. Each user has a starting and and ending date period but there are days that overlap. How do I approach this problem?

[image]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can unpivot the data and use aggregation and window functions.  This looks like:

```
select dte, sum(inc) as change_on_day,
       sum(sum(inc)) over (order by dte) as active_on_day
from ((select user, start_date as dte, 1 as inc from t) union all
      (select user, end_date, -1 from t)
     ) t
group by dte
order by dte;
```

Comment: this will not give active users for all in between dates.